# Using Max, Group By, Join and Where in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I'm try to make a complex query (instead to me), with Lambda expression. I have the SQL that I want to "translate" to Lambda.

```
SELECT MAX((SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,4,4)+SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,2,2)+SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,1,2))) as Dt, 
tb._n, tbp.number, tbp.dsc
FROM TB_A tb
JOIN TB_B_C tbp ON tbp.number = tb.number
WHERE tbp.rec = 0 AND tbp.processing = 0 AND tb._n != '' AND tbp.error = 0
GROUP BY tb._n, tbp.number, tbp.dsc
```

Until now I have this Lambda Expression:

```
var results = db.a
           .Join(db.b_c, proc => proc.number, andam => andam.number, (proc, andam) => new { proc, andam })
           .Where(d => d.proc._n != "" && d.andam.rec == false && d.andam.processing == false && d.andam.error)
           .ToList();
```

How can I finish my select to have the same result as the SQL query? If possible can you explain how to think properly when "translating" a query to Lambda?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're asking us what you're missing, tell us first what's is wrong with it.

Comment: It would also help to see your entities.  For instance if you have a navigation property from `a` to `b_c` then you don't need to do the join.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks! I've changed the way that I make my question!

Comment: here is the groupby statement. `.GroupBy(x => new { proc.Npj, andam.NumProcesso, andam.DscAndamento})`

Comment: It would be better if you stored your `dt` column as an actual date type instead of a varchar.  Then you wouldn't need all the substring functions in order to find the max value.

Comment: @juharr Agreed! But now it's too late, unfortunately!

Comment: Also it looks like your Substring arguments are wrong. The index should be 1 based for SQL and so I would assume you meant to do `SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,5,4)+SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,3,2)+SUBSTRING(tbp.dt,1,2)` To change a value like 03032016 into 20160303.

Comment: @juharr Awesome! You're right! Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried to use `GroupJoin` ?

Comment: @MaciejLos, no! How can I do that?

Comment: Check this link: http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php Please, check my answer to your another question too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually easier to write with query syntax

```
var results = from tb in db.a
              join tbp in db.b_c on tb.number equals tbp.number
              where tbp.rec == 0 
                    && tbp.processing == 0 
                    && tb._n != string.Empty 
                    && tbp.error == 0
              group new {tb, tbp}  by new {tb._n, tbp.number, tbp.dsc} into grp
              select new
              {
                  grp.Key._n,
                  grp.Key.number,
                  grp.Key.dsc,
                  Dt = grp.Max(x => x.tbp.dt.Substring(4,4) 
                                  + x.tbp.dt.Substring(2,2) 
                                  + x.tbp.dt.Substring(0,2))
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is

1) to add `GroupBy` and `Select` statements

or

2) to replace `Join` with `GroupJoin`.

Below examples are not related to your database schema...

**Option 1)**

```
var results = ...
           .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Field1, x.Field2, x.Field3})
           .Select(grp=>new
            {
               Key = grp.Key,
               MaxVal = grp.Max(o=>o.Field1)
            });
```

**Option 2)**

```
var result = db_a.Where(x=>x.Field1==1 && x.Field2==0)
            .GroupJoin(db_b.Where(x=>x.Field3==5),
                       a => a.PrimaryKey,
                       b => b.ForeignKey,
                       (a, b) => new
                           {
                               PK=a.PrimaryKey,
                               MaxVal=b.Max(o=>o.Field2)
                            });
```

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx